# Template 10 hamburger menu detail page disappears after resume

Tags: uwp, template10

[Start app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYG0G.png)
[Press home button]

[press "all apps" on home screen and the icon for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9YN4.png)

now i only see the hamburger icon. this is my suspend and resume functions.

Comment: You still are posting more code, right?

Comment: We are definitely going to need more information than that...

Comment: i got the exact same behavor if i in Visual Studio 2015 sp3 select new project template 10 (hamburger). build for arm processor. by right klick project folder select store/create app packages create appx ( not appx bundel). Copy it to my download folder on the device Honeywell gt50. install dependencies and appx. 1. Sart the app see the text box label "Parameter to Pass" value Gas. 2. klick windows button (home) on device. 3 select "all apps ->" and klick on my template10App agin. 4 Now i only see the hamburger menu in the top left corner.

Comment: I can recreate it by debug device. the app get installed on honewell gt50. now its works if i press windows button and then restart the at by press "all apps ->" click icon. even if use the lifecycle events (suspend and resume). now end the debug session. go to the device start the app and then click windows button then go to "all apps ->" and click template10app icon again. now you only see the hamburger menu.

Comment: Add those steps to the question, comments don't count here. And are harder to read.

Comment: But for what it's worth, I was able to reproduce this on a standard x86 emulator. Everything straight out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by the Template10 team. dg2k. 
All is fine.
Just change ExistingContent.Exclude to ExistingContent.Include for the following line in public override UIElement CreateRootElement(IActivatedEventArgs e) (App.xaml.cs).

```
public override UIElement CreateRootElement(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    var navService = NavigationServiceFactory(BackButton.Attach, ExistingContent.Include);

    ...
}
```