# Template 10 Navigation Bug - Windows Phone

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile, template10, hamburger-menu

I've been working on a simple Template 10 app and discovered a strange bug. After loading the app to my Windows Phone, it works fine until I switch apps then switch back by trying to reopen the application from it's tile. When I do this, the app navigates to an empty frame that has just the hamburger menu on it (regardless of what page it was on when I switched away). I have added a ton of tracing, but just couldn't figure out why it was happening. I have forced navigation in the overridden OnResuming but it seems to be ignored - based on my debugging logs, it looks like it is trying to go back to the page it was on when the app switched away.
If I force the app to quit and go back in, everything is fine - it is only when switching *back* to the app by re-launching after first switching away that it happens.
BTW - this ONLY happens on my phone. When run from a desktop it works fine.
One other bit: when run through the debugger, the problem never occurs (which is why I had to litter my code with trace messages to a log).

I wanted to come up with a simple reproducible scenario, so I tried an experiment. Using a new template 10 Hamburger project template, I created a new empty app and loaded it to my phone. This app (which has no added code) exhibits the same problem.

Has anyone else seen this?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: A possible duplicate, with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41961375/

Comment: I'll verify shortly - thanks!

Comment: Changing ExistingContent.Exclude to ExistingContent.Include on the call to CreateRootelement didn't fix it - at least not quite.
The behavior I want is regardless of the page the app was on when it was resumed, it should navigate to the app's login page. My debugging logs tell me it's navigating to the login page as I request in my code, but them immediately is navigating again to the last page. I can't seem to prevent it from returning to that page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm workin' on a project created with T10 and yes this is a bug. Also reported at github repository. See [link](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1286)